# Fortran backtrace error message with libcuba

Tags: fortran

I'm developing an integral using libcuba with Fortran, but when I go to run the program, this error appears

```
Backtrace for this error:
  0x7ff80c55d31a
  0x7ff80c55c503
  0x7ff80bbd9f1f
  0x55eb8a7eb281
  0x55eb8a7ec8e1
  0x55eb8a7c0b24
  0x55eb8a7c1785
  0x55eb8a7daf03
  0x55eb8a7d7e8f
  0x55eb8a7c34b1
  0x55eb8a7c20a9
  0x55eb8a7c1087
  0x55eb8a7c1732
  0x7ff80bbbcb96
  0x55eb8a7bbc99
  0xffffffffffffffff
Targeting failure (recorded core image)
```

The code of program is:

```
      PROGRAM Integral_E_ultra

      IMPLICIT None
      DOUBLE PRECISION NORM,VAL


      CALL E_ultra(VAL)

      STOP
      END


      SUBROUTINE E_ultra(VAL)

      IMPLICIT NONE
      DOUBLE PRECISION NORM,VAL,PI,VALG1
      DOUBLE PRECISION INTEGRALG1(1),ERRORG1(1),PROBG1(1)
      PARAMETER (PI=3.14159265358979D0)

C  Parameters related to the CUBA numerical integration:

      integer ndim,ncomp,mineval,maxeval,verbose,last
      integer fail,nregions,neval
      double precision epsrel,epsabs,userdata
      parameter (ndim=1)
      parameter (userdata=0)
      parameter (ncomp=1)
      parameter (epsrel=1D-3)
      parameter (epsabs=1D-12)

      parameter (verbose=0)
      parameter (last = 4)
      parameter (mineval=0)
      parameter (maxeval=50000)

      integer key1, key2, key3
      parameter (key1 = 47)
      parameter (key2 = 1)
      parameter (key3 = 1)

      integer nstart,nincrease
      parameter (nstart = 1000)
      parameter (nincrease = 500)

      integer nnew
      double precision flatness
      parameter (nnew = 1000)
      parameter (flatness = 25D0)

      integer key
      parameter (key =0)

      EXTERNAL INTG1


      CALL CUHRE(ndim,ncomp,INTG1,userdata,
     +     epsrel,epsabs,verbose+last,mineval,maxeval,
     +     KEY,NREGIONS,neval,fail,INTEGRALG1,ERRORG1,PROBG1)
      VALG1=INTEGRALG1(1)
      VAL=3D0*VALG1/(16*PI**3D0)

      RETURN
      END


      SUBROUTINE INTG1(NDIM,X,NCOMP,RESULT)

      IMPLICIT NONE
      DOUBLE PRECISION X(NDIM),RESULT(NCOMP)
      DOUBLE PRECISION VAR(1),RANGE,JACOBIAN,PI
      DOUBLE PRECISION UPPER(1)
      COMMON/UBOUND/ UPPER
      DOUBLE PRECISION LOWER(1)
      COMMON/UBOUND/ LOWER
      INTEGER NDIM,NCOMP,I
      PARAMETER (PI=3.14159265358979D0)
      Result = 0
      VAR = 0
      RANGE=0D0
      JACOBIAN=1D0      
      LOWER(1)=0D0
      UPPER(1)=1D0    

      DO I=1,NDIM
         RANGE=UPPER(I)-LOWER(I)
         JACOBIAN=JACOBIAN*RANGE
         VAR(I)=LOWER(I)+X(I)*RANGE
      ENDDO

      CALL INTEGRANDG1(RESULT,VAR)
      RESULT(1)=RESULT(1)*JACOBIAN

      RETURN
      END


      SUBROUTINE INTEGRANDG1(RESULT,VAR)

      IMPLICIT NONE
      DOUBLE PRECISION VAR(1),RESULT(*)
      DOUBLE PRECISION NORM,LAMBDA,ALPHA,K,M,G1
      LAMBDA = 1
      K=1
      G1 = 0
      ALPHA = VAR(1)
      G1= -(LAMBDA**2*K*M*ALPHA)/(K**2+LAMBDA**2)**2
      RESULT(1) = G1

      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And since you seem to be using gfortran, add "-g -fcheck=all -Wall" to your compile options, that might help pinpoint where your error is.

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour]. What kind of library is that? Use the flags recommended ba janneb. Double check the type and value of each and every argument you send to the subroutines and functions. The code is hard to read in a very old style. More indentation would certainly help. We may not be able to help you without the library.